Cinnamon just crashed (fallback mode)
When I type in the command cinnamon-launcher it says the following:
(cinnamon:564): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 20:49:39.594: gdk_x11_display_set_window_scale: assertion 'GDK_IS_X11_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Exception in thread Thread-2 (wait_for_process):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/cinnamon-launcher", line 87, in wait_for_process
    os.execvp(FALLBACK_COMMAND, (FALLBACK_COMMAND,) + FALLBACK_ARGS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 575, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 617, in _execvpe
    raise last_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 608, in _execvpe
    exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory


You've not yet provided your Ubuntu product & release details; what install are you asking about?
